# How to create WMTS service with geoserver and view in openlayer from geotiff?

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I have created a layer in GeoServer from GeoTIFF.It is available in layer preview pane also viewable in Openlayer from the option below.

[image]

Comment: How to use WMTS Layer into it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be moved to gis.stackexchange site

Answer (score 2):

You likely already have the WMTS for it, assuming you have the "tile caching" enabled in the layer definition panel.

Go to the WMTS capabilities document and you'll find it.
GeoServer does not offer a WMTS based layer preview, but you can code one using the OpenLayers documentation examples:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts.html